# How to align with css

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to display my subtitles with unique style. So we use the following css code for style

```
.title-1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4db2ec;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    color: #FFF }

.title-1 > span { 
    background: #4db2ec;
    width: auto;
    padding: 4px 7px }
```

Now I am insert advertisement block with following html code with wrap text.

```
<div style="float: right; margin-left: 20px;"> 
    <img src="http://domain.com/ad.jpg" height="600" width="160">
</div>
<h2 class="title-1"><span id="location">My Sub Title</span></h2>
```

now my title style is operlap in my advertisement block. how to solve this?

[image]

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f025d5Lh/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/px593mxn/

Comment: you can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/z3f6ybqd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is to add `z-index:-999;` to `.title-1`, this will *push down* the `relative` div below any `div`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/329ztxye/)

**CSS**

```
.title-1 {
    border-bottom:1px solid #4db2ec;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:16px !important;
    z-index:-999;  /* only change */
    color:#FFF
}
.title-1 > span {
    background:#4db2ec;
    width:auto;
    padding:4px 7px
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your help. Yes working fine. But lines end touch the banner add. How to avoid this. Any idea?

Comment: @Joshua : adding either `padding-left` or `margin-left` both will limit the div area :)

Comment: @Joshua : remove `border` from `img` in my fiddle, ad it looks fine as you expected => http://jsfiddle.net/329ztxye/2/

Comment: @Joshua : or simplest, define `width` in `.title-1` [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/329ztxye/3/)

Comment: @Joshua : always a pleasure mate! :)